# On a set theory booklet by T. Skolem

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic, bibliography

I recall reading a small book by T. Skolem presenting classical set theory, and I believe it was published in the late fifties while he was teaching in the United States. Does anyone have the bibliographical details?

Comment: MathSciNet has "MR0156776 Skolem, Thoralf A. Abstract set theory. Notre Dame Mathematical Lectures, No. 8 University of Notre Dame Press, Notre Dame, Ind. 1962 v+70 pp."  Could that be it?

Comment: The book mentioned by @NateEldredge seems to be [available at Project Euclid](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndml/1175197470). (Although I do not see an option to get pdf of the whole book, only for each chapter separately.)

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, I think that is it.

Comment: @NateEldredge If you want you can state an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to fit.  It's a short book published by the University of Notre Dame Press.

> [MR0156776](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0156776)  Skolem, Thoralf A. Abstract set theory. Notre Dame Mathematical Lectures, No. 8. University of Notre Dame Press, Notre Dame, Ind. 1962. v+70 pp.

As Martin Sleziak points out, it is [on Project Euclid](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndml/1175197470) and may be downloadable depending on your subscriptions.  Click the "Table of Contents" tab to get PDF links for each chapter.  Unfortunately there are a lot of short chapters and it seems they have to be downloaded separately.